# Check public key certificate

Tags: certificates, openssl

I have created public, private keys and a self signed certificate with the following commands:

```
openssl genrsa -out private-key.pem 3072
openssl rsa -in private-key.pem -pubout -out public-key.pem
openssl req -new -x509 -key private-key.pem -out cert.pem -days 360
```

Certificate output:
openssl x509 -in cert.pem -text

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            35:66:2d:64:53:3a:89:cf:47:28:b4:fe:24:42:11:c7:3c:ca:b9:d8
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = AU, ST = Some-State, L = Vilnius, O = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
        Validity
            Not Before: Apr 21 17:28:12 2022 GMT
            Not After : Apr 16 17:28:12 2023 GMT
        Subject: C = AU, ST = Some-State, L = Vilnius, O = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (3072 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:d9:fc:2b:61:a7:cb:66:a1:8e:f2:ff:c8:a3:1c:
                    af:3d:c9:69:d3:f1:80:e8:c7:2b:f2:03:8c:ea:b6:
                    34:69:8b:ed:57:58:a9:d1:96:3d:bf:75:ea:b1:8a:
                    7e:18:f4:c8:78:8d:f3:0e:3c:f0:43:cb:fc:cb:3e:
                    fa:a7:51:ee:41:de:07:dc:1f:d4:46:78:c3:30:31:
                    0f:84:11:72:32:80:11:06:5d:60:22:7c:d2:3e:a0:
                    69:5b:ef:b4:10:f7:23:b5:52:64:d8:77:27:2c:19:
                    d6:ed:43:4b:d3:6b:3e:4b:04:68:ac:d0:70:e5:db:
                    c0:54:b4:c8:03:fc:bf:7d:25:8b:87:05:ed:58:e8:
                    e9:21:7b:6d:6b:31:55:17:6c:0b:0a:03:10:44:88:
                    9c:0e:a8:f3:07:e3:17:ec:36:d3:c6:f6:79:e0:93:
                    a9:39:80:c0:ff:ff:0f:b9:25:fb:54:a7:e3:df:42:
                    5a:67:c5:c7:c5:1d:64:0e:58:59:0b:36:a0:c3:99:
                    f8:f3:2f:ac:96:04:dd:b1:07:20:52:ba:de:86:fa:
                    37:c6:9a:64:76:7d:fa:b1:ff:f2:71:45:e9:40:4f:
                    ac:e3:3c:17:bd:0d:6b:8a:96:e0:24:75:7c:52:d1:
                    f0:7c:63:2a:83:d3:2c:3b:6d:cc:f0:3d:9c:ac:a7:
                    6f:f4:c2:83:c8:a8:9c:11:79:9d:d0:ae:b9:fb:4b:
                    e8:18:86:6c:d7:c1:a0:e1:cd:55:25:ed:73:a2:74:
                    46:04:b4:6e:88:ba:67:63:ba:02:8f:30:e5:2d:9e:
                    a5:9f:87:e0:c2:fc:19:a4:03:94:ca:54:2a:b0:2e:
                    59:3b:1f:e6:80:ff:20:a4:8c:2f:84:bd:b6:98:19:
                    c9:1f:ca:14:63:6c:f1:e9:89:f6:17:4a:7a:90:72:
                    04:76:2a:2f:df:98:c5:74:0a:5b:4c:c3:42:84:09:
                    15:2c:f6:11:f4:58:4e:7d:d5:85:03:8a:75:fc:35:
                    5c:67:60:b7:6a:b1:92:40:c4:d7
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                69:02:1B:D7:9F:82:62:DC:EF:6F:BE:C7:F1:EF:3D:1C:7A:57:FD:43
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:69:02:1B:D7:9F:82:62:DC:EF:6F:BE:C7:F1:EF:3D:1C:7A:57:FD:43

            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         78:5c:ee:01:d1:dc:3d:6c:71:65:fe:f6:bb:23:a5:81:3c:60:
         d0:3f:3b:5b:ef:fc:7a:32:05:67:de:fd:f8:59:93:16:99:d2:
         5c:2f:27:80:64:6c:0e:b1:13:4e:26:1e:7a:99:23:7e:50:06:
         77:ae:ac:7c:ae:36:85:d9:02:f0:a9:b9:17:38:f4:03:3c:de:
         87:d4:db:f2:28:4c:40:0e:05:d2:b4:e7:6a:ff:1e:81:ef:48:
         d5:2e:e4:af:6d:f6:47:dd:b6:c5:65:f1:dd:83:72:7c:f5:77:
         19:b4:84:1a:8f:8a:0e:f8:06:27:3d:78:72:f1:14:12:90:47:
         a5:b8:09:f3:15:8d:9c:ae:cb:07:fb:e1:0c:6f:56:cb:cc:ca:
         9f:d9:cb:e5:ad:30:ea:b4:71:14:8d:92:08:c9:00:00:23:54:
         d8:a2:31:2d:e4:a4:10:49:2e:77:1d:a6:3d:cf:27:3f:bc:8d:
         12:69:36:78:9b:7c:0a:72:02:0e:52:2e:7e:85:40:46:13:d3:
         2c:c1:e5:d7:92:33:23:66:b6:fb:55:e2:62:47:96:c2:3c:7c:
         1d:83:a2:ca:83:66:1b:85:8a:65:d6:2d:82:e2:8e:ff:e7:4f:
         d4:e2:d4:75:ee:1b:e7:77:5c:66:09:01:f8:80:41:77:d8:11:
         53:f7:c7:de:b4:d6:24:58:39:56:c9:b3:8d:69:2a:bb:2b:83:
         d3:a3:23:42:17:73:f7:d6:38:8c:e5:b7:53:d0:e9:03:88:50:
         72:78:76:0d:67:b2:02:ba:63:e8:5a:09:a9:b1:88:83:f1:b1:
         d5:6d:d3:f4:1f:99:10:a6:cd:62:ab:13:43:f3:e4:68:0c:b6:
         bb:5d:61:6f:f2:ec:1d:d3:e6:b9:39:30:8d:f2:b2:4d:e3:5a:
         bd:27:51:3e:25:5b:aa:d6:a1:74:18:27:e0:78:31:7b:ff:be:
         75:4f:78:25:36:2c:0f:51:da:32:32:6a:b3:28:0f:19:0c:03:
         47:da:09:94:b7:6c
```

I need to check this certificate signature with public key that certificate contains. What kind of operation is it and how I can achieve this? I can see the signature and public key in HEX mode in the certificate. How can I use them?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using OpenSSL

```
openssl verify -check_ss_sig -CAfile cert.pem cert.pem
```

If you mean you want to do it 'by hand' so that you see the exact data being signed (but still with OpenSSL), the output from `x509 -text` is not sufficient because it does not fully represent everything in the certificate body. The cert.pem file (or its DER equivalent) is sufficient. See [Manually walking through the signature validation of a certificate](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/127095/manually-walking-through-the-signature-validation-of-a-certificate) (disclosure: partly mine) for the procedure on a CA-issued (*not* self-signed) cert, but you can use the same procedure on self-signed just by using your own public key in place of the CA/issuer's public key in the last step.